# Google Script - Populate google Forms multipleChoiceItem AND pageBreak with google sheet's values

Tags: arrays, google-apps-script, methods

I try to populate a google forms multipleChoiceItem with a lot of Item from my google sheet AND also configure the pagebreak (conditionnal answers) from my google sheet

**EDIT: There Is my code, Hope it is easier to understand my problem**

```
function AutoPopulateGF() {
var form = FormApp.openById("1fyej6DSh2B1spsurOR-gnD5s1NWrekt4Sf8xiIL7EjY");
var items = form.getItems();
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById("1hEBCEvUqJHnRuRqZS0FmhOZhOKG4PMa83czvdn01qcM").getSheetByName("Remplir ICI")
var data = ss.getDataRange().getValues();
var numrows = ss.getDataRange().getLastRow()

for (var i in items) { 
  if (items[i].getTitle() == 'Choisissez le module ') {
/*
//THIS BELOW IS NOT WORKING
    items[i].asMultipleChoiceItem().setChoices([
      for (var j = 0; j < numrows; ++j) {
        var column = data[j];
        if (column[0] != "") {
        items[i].asMultipleChoiceItem().createChoice(column[0],form.getItemById(column[30]).asPageBreakItem()),
    }
    }
    ])
 */

//THIS WORKS BUT VERY TIME CONSUMMING... (I HAVE MORE THAN 200 LINES)
    items[i].asMultipleChoiceItem().setChoices([ 
      items[i].asMultipleChoiceItem().createChoice(ss.getRange("A70").getValues(),form.getItemById(ss.getRange("AD70").getValues()).asPageBreakItem()),
      items[i].asMultipleChoiceItem().createChoice(ss.getRange("A71").getValues(),form.getItemById(ss.getRange("AD71").getValues()).asPageBreakItem()),
      items[i].asMultipleChoiceItem().createChoice(ss.getRange("A72").getValues(),form.getItemById(ss.getRange("AD72").getValues()).asPageBreakItem()),
      items[i].asMultipleChoiceItem().createChoice(ss.getRange("A73").getValues(),form.getItemById(ss.getRange("AD73").getValues()).asPageBreakItem()),
      items[i].asMultipleChoiceItem().createChoice(ss.getRange("A74").getValues(),form.getItemById(ss.getRange("AD74").getValues()).asPageBreakItem())
    ])
}
}
}
```

How to Automate the process ?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: What is `arr` of `list.setChoices(arr)` and `I try to write this in a automatique way and I use a loop for to push each line inside an array (call it "arr"),`?

Comment: arr is an array with my instruction: list.createChoice("NUTRI",form.getItemById("496337843").asPageBreakItem()), list.createChoice("CUTM",form.getItemById("496337843").asPageBreakItem()), list.createChoice("ONLY",form.getItemById("496337843").asPageBreakItem()),...

Comment: Could you show us the code you use to create the array?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: I put the code above (by editing my original message) :)